# PHPstorm project navigation

Tags: phpstorm

How to select opened file in projects list in PHPstorm? I mean, have a PHPstorm "select in projects" Netbeans function analog.

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm only for SF2 projects, really the SF2 plugin it's very very well. But for the other projects I use NetBeans. Works better with project groups, with pannel distribution, with code rearrange and the vi plugin... in example. Yes I know, i'm not a hipster ;-)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`Navigate` (`View` in older versions) | `Select In...` | `Project View`. It's also possible to enable `Autoscroll from source` option in the `Project View` settings.

Comment: I usually use hotkey Alt+F1 to open Select In... menu faster.

Answer (score 24):

In PHPStorm 6, the project tool window provides `Scroll from Source` [image: scroll from source] button, which i believe, does what you want. Take note though that the button will only appear once `Autoscroll from Source` is unchecked from the window settings which can be accessed by clicking the cogwheel icon [image: autoscroll from source]

Looking for this as well and stumbled on this question so I'll provide my answer here.

Answer (score 14):

Alt + F1 + 1 (for project window)

Alt + F1, will show a list from which you could select a window by pressing a number or use mouse.

Answer (score 6):

While NetBeans allows you to do this all in one keyboard shortcut, I couldn't find one shortcut to accomplish this. But with the following process you can accomplish it in two easy keystrokes.

For PhpStorm 5:

1. Open the Preferences dialog box and select `Keymap` on the left.
2. Use the search box for "Select In" or navigate in the tree to `Main menu` > `Navigate` > `Select In...` then right-click on it and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`.
3. Select the top box `First Stroke` and press the key combination on your keyboard you want to use to initiate the `Select In...` dialog box.
4. Click the `OK` button to close the Preferences window and accept the new keymap.
5. Hit the key combination from Step 3. A small dialog box opens. Notice option `1. Project View` is selected by default. Simply press `[ENTER]` or `1` and the currently open file will be highlighted in your Project pane.

[image: PhpStorm Navigate > Select In... dialog box]

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> works in PHPStorm 5.x and is the accelerator for the answer given by @crazycoder