# How to navigate to path of the opened file in project tool window in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to navigate to path of the opened file, in project tool window in IDEA? ctrl+mouse1 shows path in nautilus. I need to see path in project tool. I cant find answer ANYWHERE!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically navigate to the current class in Intellij Idea Project Tool Window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416111/how-to-automatically-navigate-to-the-current-class-in-intellij-idea-project-tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigate` | **Select In**, **Project View**, or enable **Autoscroll from Source** option, the same applies for all IntelliJ IDEA based products, so this question actually duplicates:

- [How to automatically navigate to the current class in Intellij Idea Project Tool Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11416111/104891)
- [PHPstorm project navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10754709/104891)
- [How to find out which class I'm currently in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11595319/104891)